# How does git know when there is change in the local repo?

Tags: git, hash, storage, checksum

When you change a file in the working directory, git know exactly what file changed. how does it know?

Q1) Does it calculate a checksum at the time of commits and recalculates it on event driven change eg new file created in the working directory.

Q2) Does your local drive apart from the working directory files keep the rest of the files in some location which grows as you include more projects? My drive seems fuller `C:\Users\<USER NAME>\Downloads\.git\objects`  with the addition of a new folder I was trying to track and now i would like to undo the folder I was trying to track, How do I reclaim that space. 
I was trying to do something fancy with GIT like keep track of changes on my local project files and other documents so i see the documents that had changed and update my backup with only those files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git calculates a hash from a file's contents and stores a snapshot at commit time. The hash is used both as the identifier for the content, and an easy way to compare the snapshot to a later version.

So if you have a committed version of a file, and a working-copy version, all Git has to do is calculate a hash value for the working file and compare it to the already-calculated hash from the committed snapshot. If the hashes aren't the same, then it knows something has changed. This calculation only happens when you ask (e.g. `git status` or `git diff`). It is not constantly checking on its own.

Git stores everything in the repository. This is usually found in the `.git/` directory at the root of your project. The entire repository history and contents are inside, so depending what your history contains, sometimes they do get large. That is really project-dependent. Git is good at compressing the contents, but if you're adding big pre-compressed files, it can only do so much to shrink them.

The `.git/objects/` directory you mention in your question is the main content storage in the git repository. All of the file snapshots and metadata (like the directory structure, commit objects, tags) are stored there. So it is normal that it would be the largest section of the repository folder.

Unmaking a git repository is easy - just delete the `.git` folder. However, this is a destructive action which you can't undo. Only remove it if you're okay with losing the repository history (or, if you've made a copy someplace else like GitHub, or a backup copy, and you're okay with relying on that other copy).